# Whether “to continue” or “should continue” is used in the example provided?

Tags: word-form

An example of a pattern of sentence that regularly appears in the newspaper is as follows:

> Kerala Chief Minister demanded the NITI (a new institution) **continue** the functions of the erstwhile Planning Commission.

In the above sentence, which form of the verb “continue” (“to continue” or “should continue”) is used?

Comment: I think it's effectively a [subjunctive](http://www.english-at-home.com/grammar/using-the-subjunctive-form-in-english/). Thus *"The leader of the opposition party demanded [that] the NITI **be** disbanded"*. We don't use this form in speech very much, but if we *do* use it, we're likely to include ***should*** before the "subjunctive/infinitive" verb.

Answer (score 1):

In formal writing, the quoted text is the only correct form. It is the subjunctive form of *continue*, being used to express wishes and demands.

It's more obvious with an example involving an irregular verb:

> I ask that you *be* on time tomorrow.

However, since the subjunctive is gradually losing favour in English, especially spoken English, it is somewhat common to observe usages like what you suggested. I would consider them incorrect, but that is a prescriptivist judgement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the authority structure between the *Kerala Chief Minister* and *NITI*.
If *NITI* can be ordered to continue, and since it is a *demand*, *continue* (or perhaps *shall continue*) by itself is fine.

Otherwise, use *should continue* since we can't suppose what the outcome will be.